# trigger function from autocomplete input selection

Tags: jquery

I have an input field that will autocomplete an address, I want an address selection to trigger a function.

html

```
Address: <input id="searchTextField" type="text" autocomplete="on" runat="server" />
```

JS

```
$('input[searchTextField]').bind('autocompleteSelect', function() {
  // some code...
});
```

I feel like I'm not anywhere close with the above...

Comment: why don't you just use `$("#searchTextField").bind()`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to do this.

```
$("#searchTextField" ).autocomplete({
    change: function( event, ui ) {
        // The code you want after selection is made
    }
});
```

Comment: That looks promising, but I get TypeError: $(...).autocomplete is not a function

Comment: @Bwyss, Have you loaded the jQuery UI?

Comment: It seems to work, but when I have selected an address a second time

Comment: @Bwyss, Can you show me the demo? Its better if you ask different question as it is a different problem. :) We will be glad to help you there.